# detect nested attribute validation existance ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

is there a correct way to detect whether a nested object is going to be validated when parent object will be saved? there is _validators hash for objects where I can do something like this "parent_object._validators[:object_i_am_interested_in].empty?" but is there a cleaner way?